# CQ Login with own messages

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, aem, j-security-check

Is it possible to programm an own servlet to login in CQ System and return the own message as JSON responses.

I mean the same as the J_Security_Check do, but that I have the control of the messages. Login should check credentials and create token for the session.

I don't found any helpful solution in the internet.

Does somebody know how I can do that?

Are there any classes in AEM to help in this situation?

I use AEM 6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Sling, and thus Adobe Experience Manager, allows you to create custom authentication handlers.

See:

- http://www.wemblog.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-authentication.html
- http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/authentication.html
- http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/authentication/authentication-authenticationhandler.html
- http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling8/org/apache/sling/auth/core/spi/AuthenticationHandler.html

Comment: i've already seen this article. but this shows just how to login with other authentications, like LDAP or something, but I have to login as User in CQ System from my Application, the users dont have mutch rights, but in my application they can add comments, and do votings etc...

Comment: You can use a custom authentication handler to handle normal authentication with regular Sling/AEM users. I might have a code sample I did for Sling application a while back. I will post it here if I can find it.

Comment: thanks a code sampe would be great, so I can understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at LDAP with SAML2 authentication options. 
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/saml-demo.html

Comment: thanks for your help, but it's not what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override AEM's login component present at `/libs/granite/core/content/login` by copying this component under `/apps` maintaining the same folder structure (type of various folders in the heriarchy). This component's resource is present at `/libs/granite/core/components/login` which contains the JSP script for AEM's login form. Once you've moved all the relevant scripts to `/apps`, you can modify the login form's action in login.jsp to point to your servlet path.

The call to server is submitted from `/libs/granite/core/content/login/clientlib/login.js` using Jquery, you can handle the response from your servlet in the appropriate success/error blocks.

Other than this, there is an OSGI setting which is used by AEM for rendering the login page. Find the `Day CQ Login Selector Authentication Handler` setting in Felix console and change the `Default Login Page` to your component under `/apps`.

Comment: that would be too much. I don't want to change the default login page. I need my login form in my application, and just there, the other login from cq is needed too.